# Might the derivative be a measure of a shrinking curve instead of a point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, intuition, infinity, infinitesimals

I see a lot of posts here questioning the validity of ‘instantaneous rate of change’ and most responses point to the epsilon–delta definition of a limit (or at least some informal version of it). My understanding is that with this definition we calculate the average change of a function across some non-zero interval, and then continue to decrease the interval **to no end**, at least in principle.

Since this process never ends, the object of study is always a curve, not a point. Albeit, it is an ever shrinking curve but it is a curve nonetheless. In one breath we stress that the interval **never actually becomes zero**, but then in the next breath we claim that the derivative corresponds to the slope of the tangent line **at a point**. To me this seems to be a contradictory view.

I have a view on this issue for which I would love to hear your criticisms. I argue that the issue stems from us constructing continua from points when we should be constructing points from continua. To explain my view, consider how we draw graphs. We start with a blank piece of paper (a continuum of sorts) and draw lines on it (i.e. axis lines, grid lines, functions, etc.). Only once these lines intersect can we identify points. With this construction, points are emergent, not fundamental. Since we can continue adding lines **to no end**, we’ll never completely fill the paper with ink. There will always be continua in between the lines. Might the derivative describe not the points, but the shrinking continua adjacent to the points?

My apologies if I was unclear in the last paragraph, I provided more details on this view in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/PSzqoQ9J5yg?t=115) if you are interested.

I believe that continuum-based constructions don’t face the problem of completeness and paradoxes of actual infinity present with point-based constructions. As such, it’s a view that I find hard to let go of but I want to let go of it if it’s wrong. So I would appreciate it if you can point out problems with this view.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your main claim/question is. Are you claiming there is something logically wrong with the standard epsilon delta approach to derivatives? Are you asking for reasons we typically define a graph by points? Are you saying "here's one intuition about the derivative; where does it run into trouble?"? Are you asking "is there a formalism that is closer to the intuition I've outlined here?" Or maybe "is there a counter-intuition that might be more appealing than what I've outlined here?". Are you just asking "what do you think about this?"(Too broad/opinion-based for MSE)?

Comment: My main comment/question is 'here's [a much better] intuition about the derivative; where does it run into trouble [and why is it not actually better]?'
I'm not claiming that there is something logically wrong with the standard-epsilon delta approach to derivatives, aside from the conclusion that it describes a point. Instead, I'm claiming that the standard-epsilon delta approach doesn't agree with the point-based view but instead it agrees with a continuum-based view.

I believe we typically define a graph by points because we believe it's completeness is a favorable quality.

Answer (score 2):

> the interval **never actually becomes zero**, but…slope of the tangent line **at a point**. To me this seems to be a contradictory view.

If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then "the tangent line at $a$" or "the tangent line through $a$" refers to a particular line through the point $(a,f(a))$ (specifically, the one with slope $f'(a)$). There's at most one tangent line for each point $(b,f(b))$ on the graph, so we can speak of the tangent line at a point, if it exists. I don't see any problem with this terminology.

I'm not sure, but it seems like you might be objecting to the fact that defining the derivative (the slope of the tangent line) involves *secant* lines which always pass through two relevant points on the graph. My personal gut reaction is "That's why we don't call it the 'secant' line at the point. The different word 'tangent' is used for that reason."

> the issue stems from us constructing continua from points when we should be constructing points from continua.

I'm not certain I understand what you're getting at here, but it seems like your idea might not work well for an example like $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{2} & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$. There are holes in the parabola part of that graph, and it's not anything like a simple contiguous curve near $(0,0)$, but it's still differentiable at $0$ and so most would say it still has a tangent line there.

> Since we can continue adding lines **to no end**, we’ll never completely fill the paper with ink.

I'm having trouble understanding what this part of the discussion has to do with the derivatives part, but this depends sensitively on how (or "how fast") we add lines. For example, if I want to fill the unit square with vertical line segments, let's just say I fill $x=0$ through $x=t$ by time $t$, so that by time $0.1$ I've already added a continuum's worth of lines. Then I'll completely fill the square by time $1$.

Comment: I am objecting to using 'finite' math (i.e. secants and division by non-zero terms) to make sense of 'infinite' math (i.e tangents and division by zero). If we accept that the derivative corresponds to the slope of a tangent line through a point then we must accept irrational numbers (since many tangent lines would have an irrational slope) and, consequently, we must accept the Axiom of Infinity. Are we justified in saying that "we can speak of a tangent line at a point"? Or more pointedly, are we justified in axiomatizing infinity into existence?

Comment: If irrational numbers do not exist, then there are no holes in the parabola part of the graph. And if an infinite number of tasks cannot actually be completed, then we cannot fill x=0 through x=t. Would you say that these criticisms rely on the Axiom of Infinity being valid?

Comment: By the way, Mark, thanks so much for your response. It truly is refreshing to finally get feedback from a mathematician.

Comment: @RyanO'Connor Most of those sentences deserve multiple paragraph responses. I can't respond well in a couple comments, but I'll try to give an initial response, and encourage you to post things like those as separate MSE questions. Numbering responses to your seven sentences in order: 1. I feel like the point of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ was to avoid confusion about infinitesimals or anything. 2. You don't have derivatives of non-polynomials without irrational numbers, but you don't need to use the axiom of infinity/set theory, per se. Reals without set theory is studied in "Reverse Mathematics".

Comment: 3. I argued for "yes" in my answer. 4. Depending on how you mean this, either "yes, absolutely" or perhaps "that's a matter of personal opinion about philosophy of mathematics, but as a formalist I personally am fine with any axiom whatsoever". 5. Removing the rational numbers from consideration does not make the rationals complete. 6. Sure, but I don't think that's a very useful observation. 7. If you're basing your math on set theory (which isn't necessary), then even the naturals rely on the Axiom of Infinity. 8.&9. I'm happy to engage, but I recommend focusing on one or two Qs at a time.

Comment: Separate MSE questions doesn't allow for much of a conversation, but you're completely right. As long as I'm asking questions on MSE I should stick with the format and focus on one or two Qs at a time. As tempting as it is to respond to all of your comments, I will hold off on responding to the off topic ones. I'll submit new Qs on those topics. If you decide to respond to those Qs, I will be very grateful.

Comment: 1. I wonder whether the move to epsilon-delta should have been accompanied by a move to a continuum-based view.
2. Rejecting irrational numbers does not imply rejecting irrational derivatives. The way I see it is that one can't actually complete the calculation of an irrational derivative (any more than one can list all digits of pi). Cantor said that "the transfinite numbers stand or fall with the finite irrational numbers; they are alike in their most intrinsic nature".

Comment: 5. The rationals are not complete. With the continuum-based view, in between rational points lies the continua where change happens.
6. It is a useful observation if we want to limit ourselves to what is actually possible. One can go down the wrong path if they give too much weight to impossible scenarios.

Comment: Correction: 5. With the continuum-based view, your definition of f(x) is impossible because we cannot actually define infinite points. If there is a fundamental limit to which we can write out the coordinates of a point (i.e. if we cannot completely write out an irrational number) then we cannot construct that point (and say that the function value is 0 there). And if a function only contains rational points (i.e. no continuum in between those points), I don't think we can say that it has a tangent line at (0,0).

Comment: Clarification: 2. The way I see it is that since we can't actually complete the calculation of an irrational derivative, then what we actually do is interrupt the calculation partway through and produce a rational approximation. So we can either define it precisely as an infinite process or imprecisely as a rational number. Why do we need to say that the infinite process can be completed to produce an irrational number?

Comment: @RyanO'Connor I'm not going to try to respond to most of your comments here. the Q&A part of stackexchange is not intended to allow for a conversation - this has benefits because it requires the question answer to set up one question well and allows the answerers time to answer it in detail without risk of a changing topic as in a conversation. But it has downsides, which is why there is Chat as well. "impossible scenarios" This is dangerously close to an extreme claim like "the axiom of infinity doesn't just obscure useful intuition/a perspective I like, but leads to a logical contradiction".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116247/discussion-between-mark-s-and-ryan-oconnor).